# Rounded result even casting to float

Tags: java

I don't know why java is rounding result. I used casting to float, I was adding '.0f'. Nothing want to work. I know that double is better for dividing but I don't need very precision result.

```
int A = Integer.parseInt(listBytesAnsw.get(2), 16); //ex. 18
int B = Integer.parseInt(listBytesAnsw.get(3), 16); //ex. 226
float rpm = (float) (A*255+B)/4; //Ans=1204 wrong, should be 1203.75

float rpm = (float) (A*255.0f+B)/4.0f; //dont work still 1204
```

Comment: `/4` is an **integer divison**, no matter if you cast the upper part of the fraction to a flow. You should divide by `4.0f` to get the result you want.

Comment: It's not working even I add as you say

Comment: No, your example is wrong. 
rpm = (A*255+B)/4.0 = (18*255 + 226)/4.0 = 4816 / 4.0 = 1204.0
Using the example values, the result *is* 1204.

Comment: Ohh, I dont know where from I get this example. I didn't check it. My bad

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt a float / int => float.

Comment: This is correct and I never stated otherwise. I just noted that `float / int` as in *integer divison* by 4 is what's happening here, but OP wants `float / float` (well, `int/float` actually, there's no float precision in the numerator).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The result you get is to be expected. After all:

```
255*226 = 4816
4816 / 4 = 1204
```

Of course, rounding and then casting would not work in case you have indeed a non-integer result. So look at the following code

```
System.out.println("(float)(7/4)=" + ((float)(7/4)));
System.out.println("(float)7/4=" + ((float)7/4));
System.out.println("(7+0.0f)/4=" + ((7+0.0f)/4));
System.out.println("7/(4+0.0f)=" + (7/(4+0.0f)));
```

results in

```
(float)(7/4)=1.0
(float)7/4=1.75
(7+0.0f)/4=1.75
7/(4+0.0f)=1.75
```

The first does not work as you found out. But either of the other solutions works.

Comment: No need for the addition.  (float)(7) / 4 = 1.75

Comment: Already added. you don't the brackets around the 7 either